# Docking a form onto another form

Tags: c#, .net

I have a form which contains some controls (similar to visual studio toolbox). This form is a top level control. I want to dock this form on another form. Is it possible? How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Docking a form to another form panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427310/docking-a-form-to-another-form-panel)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at UserControls. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to establish a parent/child relationship.  If that is the case, set the child's parent to be the container form (the MDI container - set IsMDIContainer to true).  That will at least allow you to create a relationship between the two forms.  However, if you are thinking about docking where you pin and unpin a section and it hides/shows itself, I do not believe Visual Studio allows this natively.  You would need to get a third-party control to do so.  I would recommend the Telerik controls, since they are great to use and they have wonderful docking.  Also, you might be able to do something without using third-party controls if you used WPF instead of Winforms but I'm not totally certain on that point.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the answer provided here: [moving and placing child window near parent window C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463899/moving-and-placing-child-window-near-parent-window-c/5465186#5465186) if you change the `_offset` value in the demo to 0 you can see a way to "dock" two forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Dock Panel Suite :
http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/